# If $x\in [0,1)$ then there exists $n\in \mathbb N$, $x\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}$ ?

Tags: real-numbers

I'm trying to show that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N^*}[0,1-\dfrac{1}{n}]=[0,1)$ and I'm stuck at the following step:

If $x\in [0,1)$ how to justify that there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $x\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}$ ?

It seems like an Archimedean property but I can't see how to use it:
$\forall x>0$ and $\forall y>0$ there exists a  positive integer $n $ such that $nx>y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$x\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}\iff \frac1n\le 1-x\iff n\ge \frac{1}{1-x}.$$

So, it is enough to take

$$n=\left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right]+1$$ where $[]$ denotes the integer part.

Comment: Simply Archimidean property was enough for this problem

Answer (score 2):

"∀x>0 and ∀y>0 there exists a positive integer n such that nx>y"

Right.  So let $x' = 1-x > 0$ and $y = 1$.   So  there is an $n$ so that $nx' > y$

... or in other words.... $n(1-x) > 1$

... or in other words $(1-x) > \frac 1n$

... or in other words $1-\frac 1n > x$.

=====

Perhaps more direct.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ then there is a $\frac 1n < \epsilon$.  So just let $\epsilon = 1- x$. and you get $0 < \frac 1n < 1-x$.

=====

How do we justify that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\frac 1n < \epsilon$?  Or for that matter how do we justify the Archmedian principal that there is an $n$ so that $nx > y$?

Well.... if $1 > \epsilon = 1 - x > 0$ then $\frac 1{\epsilon} > 1$ and we can find an $n$ so that $n > \frac 1{\epsilon}$ which means $\frac 1n < \epsilon$.

Likewise if $n > \frac yx$ then  ... well, ....

Answer (score 0):

We have $x \lt 1$, so $1-x\gt0$, so $1/(1-x)\gt0$, so by Archimedian property there is a natural number $n$ such that $1/(1-x)\leq n$, or $1/n\leq 1-x$, or $x\leq 1-1/n$.